# At the university: office worker, clerk or something else?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Some students and university workers (not the academic staff) participated in my study. Which words are better to describe them? Are there any other better alternatives?

> The normal participants were recruited from available **students and clerks/office workers** in the
>   Faculty of Education and Psychology of University of Mashhad.

Comment: If the clerks/office workers are employed by the university, they _are_ staff...

Comment: @user8543 I meant I don't want the word to include the academic staff, i.e. the the professors.

Comment: I suppose there may be room for ambiguity, but the word _staff_ is often meant to **not** include professors. Universities employ _faculty_ and _staff_ - _staff_ are the employees who are not teaching.

Comment: @J.R. Here, in India, all schools have a *staff room* where *teachers* sit, read or discuss. Said that, [*staff room*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staff_room) is for those who teach.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the phrase *administrative staff*, to differentiate between the teaching faculty, and to cover any staff that might not consider themselves 'just' clerks.

Comment: I think the word _staff_ already differentiates – at least, it would in the U.S. Adding the word _administrative_ would not help differentiate between faculty and staff, but it might help differentiate between, say, clerical staff and janitorial staff.

Comment: I wouldn't consider a lecturer/teacher to be part of the admin staff

Comment: I wouldn't consider a lecturer to be part of the staff at all. The lecturer is part of the faculty, not the staff. I think that is the root of the O.P.'s misunderstanding here. I think your initial comment was spot on; the word the O.P. is looking for is probably _staff_.

Comment: I believe that the use of the word faculty in reference to a body of teaching staff is much more widespread in America than it is elsewhere. It is very rarely used in the UK for example.

Comment: That's good to know. In the U.S., _staff_ would be the right word for this. (Incidentally, I work on two college campuses in the U.S., so I'm a bit familiar with this nomenclature. But I always appreciate learning more about how such terms aren't necessarily universally defined.)

Comment: In UK universities you might well have "academic staff" and "non academic staff" (and even odder varieties such as "academic related staff" - a job I did once). A "faculty" is an organisational unit in many universities.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S., I think the way you would want to word this is:

> The normal participants were recruited from available students and staff in the Faculty of Education and Psychology of University of Mashhad.

In academia, the professors are *faculty*, and the office workers are *staff*. If you mean to say that the participants were comprised of students and administrative assistants, then you should use the word word *staff*.